# WPF binding problem with LINQ-class

Tags: .net, wpf, linq, binding

I have a WPF-page (ZorgTrajectPage1.xaml) with a code-behind ZorgTrajectPage1.xaml.cs with a DependencyProperty ZorgtrajectController called Ztc.

The dataContext is set in the Page_Loaded() of ZorgTrajectPage1.xaml:

```
Ztc = new ZorgTrajectController();
DataContext = Ztc;
```

It appears that I can access this ZorgTrajectController via binding to look up a integer in this Controller (patientID-variable):

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Path=PatientID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

This works perfect. But I also have a comboBox that selects an educatiePakket. When this selection is made, the selectedEducatiePakket is looked up via a LINQ-query and put in a variable in a ZorgTrajectController. This SelectedEducatiePakket is a new instance of a LINQ-class (that has a String-property with it's name, called naam). I used the following method to fill it up:

```
SelectedEducatiepakket = SelectedEducatiePakketByID(5);

public educatiepakket SelectedEducatiePakketByID(int id)
        {
            educatiepakket ep = (from o in db.educatiepakkets
                                 where o.educatiepakket_id == id
                                 select o).Single() as educatiepakket;
            return ep;
        }
```

Tthe following:

```
<TextBox Name="EPNaamTxtbx" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedEducatiepakket.naam, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

doesn't work. I totally don't understand why this isn't working. I've made a button which in the code-behind Console.WriteLines information of the Ztc. It says there is a selectedEducatiePakket, but my textbox isn't showing any information of it.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Visual Studio -> Debug -> Windows -> Output` should show you all binding errors while debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `ZorgTrajectController` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fires the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `SelectedEducatiePakket` property. Something like this:

```
public educatiepakket SelectedEducatiePakket 
{
   get { return _selectedEducatiePakket; }
   set 
   {
      _selectedEducatiePakket = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEducatiePakket");
   }
}
```

If that doesn't help, run your project under debugger and after the property `SelectedEducatiePakket` is supposed to be set look in the Visual Studio's Output window. There might be some information about binding errors.

Comment: I'll try that right away. I thought that wasn't needed, because the auto-generated LINQ-classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged already, but I have to implement it in ZTC too? I don't think I have any binding errors anymore when I run/Debug. Is this iNotifyPropertyChanged not necessary with ints? Since it DOES work for that PatientID but not for the SelectedEducatiePakket..

Comment: @Trinorae - INotifyPropertyChanged IS necessary. With PatientID it works because this property is not changed in run-time (binding reads it ones when DataContext changes), while SelectedEducatiePakket is changed every time you select something in the ComboBox. Just think logically, how the binding system is supposed to know that it has to re-read the value of that property when you change it in the code?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just started working with WPF and binding and thought the Controller, which is just a "in-between-class" would just delegate it to the LINQ-class (which implements that interface), but as you said this wasn't enough. I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in my controller and now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I see a typo. Your Binding is for `SelectedEducatiepakket.naam` but you said, the property is named `SelectedEducatiePakket`. Difference: "p" <-> "P" in "Pakket".

Comment: Thanks! Because of errors like this I am sometimes using BindingFinder: http://robrelyea.com/demos/bindingFinder/

Comment: That was just a typo I made here. My apologies for that!